# bypass frp on motorola moto e20

Tags: motorola-moto-e, frp

Before christmas I bought a motorola moto e20 for my grandparents.
I set it up but for some reasons I didn't write down any credentials and account information and I forgot everything.

So I though I'll factory reset it only to discover the thing that's frp.

Is there any way to bypass it?
I already contacted motorola support and waiting for a reply.

I still have the original receipt and package with the IMEI on it so I can really prove that I legally purchased the phone.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered (usually with the link above) a hundred times here... If FRP was easy to bypass, it wouldn't be worth anything at all. It is extremely difficult to bypass and requires specific exploits on a phone by phone basis (often limited to specific software versions) if it is even possible at all. I would say bypassing this is realistically impossible in 99% of cases. Sorry, but if you can't figure out the account and how access it, you may just have a brick.

Comment: while all what acejavelin said is true, there is one other solution: send the phone back to motorola with prove of purchase. According to their support, they are able to fix (for a price, still waiting on a quote)

Comment: I wish you luck with that... not sure where you live but in the US I haven't heard of Motorola doing this unless it was under warranty, and even then it often took just getting lucky and most people just get told, "sorry, buy another one".

Comment: I think somebody should reopen the question because I have found a solution:
Motorola is able to reset FRP.
I just got my phone back and it worked, but it costed quite a lot (almost 130CHF in switzerland, which is more than the phone itself, so not a very economic solution, but a ecologic one, thats why I did it)

Comment: This question is a duplicate, and your experience is highly unusual... I know in many markets this isn't an option. I am surprised you were able to get this done. The answers in the question marked as a duplicate are about bypassing FRP _yourself_ and not via the manufacturer.